# Function Keep Triggering Before JSON Done Processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

**Function 1: Get JSON Data & Store**

I am creating a script where an array of twitch channels will go through the JSON function loop to be processed and then stored using **"localStorage.setItem"** as temporary storage. I'm saving them in name,viewer and url.

**Function 2: Sort Data**

Stored data can later be used to display the information without having to use function 1 again.

---

**Problem**

The sortdata function keeps on firing before function 1 is complete. Resorting in error because the data is undefined. This error popped before the console displays all the information stored from function 1.

My code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $.when(getData()).promise().done(function(){
      getStoredObj();
  });
});

function getData(){
  var streamArray=[];

  jQuery.each (channels, function (i, channel) {
    channelId = channel.id;
    channelUrl = channel.url;

      var promise = $.ajax({
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: twitchApi + channelId,
        success: 1,
        }).done(function ( data ) {

          if (data.stream == null) {

          } else {
            var displayName = data.stream.channel.display_name;
            var viewerCount = data.stream.viewers;
            streamArray.push({name: displayName, views: viewerCount, url: channelUrl});            

            localStorage.setItem("storedStreamArray", JSON.stringify(streamArray));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(streamArray));
          }
      });
  });
}

function getStoredObj () {
  var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('storedStreamArray');
  var parsedObject = JSON.parse(retrievedObject);

  <sorting codes here>
}
```

Some help here really appreciated. :)

Comment: place the sorting code in the ajax success function

Comment: I added getStoredObj() outside of the loop in getData(). Doesn't work, getStoredObj() still fired before localStorage.

Comment: see http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/

Comment: Turned off async using "async: false," in the ajax json function. Now I'm good.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `$.when` with the result of `getData`, but `getData` doesn't return anything, let alone a deferred that `when` can use. As a result, there's nothing to wait for and your `done` callback calls `getStoredObj` immediately.

In `getData`, you need to collect all the deferreds returned by your `ajax` calls and pass them back to the caller. That would look like:

```
function getData(){
  return jQuery.map (channels, function (i, channel) {
      return $.ajax(...).done(function ( data ) {
        // Do work
      });
  });
}
```

Each iteration returns its `ajax` deferred, which are aggregated by `map` and returned to the caller. Then you can run `when` on the result and wait for loading to finish before you sort anything.